# Problem performing mouseover and comparing the color of element

Tags: hover, cypress

I am trying to perform the mouse hover action for a demo site and have an issue when performing a mouse hover.

I want to check the color or the text on hover, but I am failing to do so.

Website : https://demo.nopcommerce.com/

steps : login to application
select  the regisration ,
consider the locator and ,
perform the mouse  hover.

my code:

```js
cy.visit('https://demo.nopcommerce.com/')
cy.get('.ico-register')
 .trigger('mouseover')
 .should('have.css', 'cursor', 'pointer')
 .wait(1000) // Adjust the delay time as needed
 .should('have.css', 'color', 'rgb(74, 178, 241)')
```

error :

> assert expected <a.ico-register> to have CSS property color with the value rgb(74, 178, 241), but the value was rgb(119, 119, 119)
> AssertionError
> expected '<a.ico-register>' to have CSS property 'color' with the value 'rgb(74, 178, 241)', but the value was 'rgb(119, 119, 119)'

note :
1: rgb(119, 119, 119) this is before hover color it is showing same as the after hover

2: in this , when i am trying to  hover manually  on the registration tab , the test case is        passing

Answer (score 5):

The problem with using `trigger` event to test a hover action is that Cypress trigger command only works for javascript effects on the element.

For example, if the element has a javascript event handler like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event)

> ```js
> addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => {});
>
> onmouseover = (event) => {};
> ```

then `.trigger('mouseover')` will fire that handler.

But many links have CSS changes based on hover, and these are not fired by `.trigger('mouseover')`.

If you open dev-tools, navigate to styles pane and turn on the hover checkbox you can see the CSS color style that is applied.

[image]

---

**Use [cypress-real-events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events)**

This third party library is able to trigger CSS transitions as well as javascript transitions with it's `.realHover()` command

```js
cy.visit('https://demo.nopcommerce.com/')

cy.get('.ico-register')
  // .trigger('mouseover')
  .realHover()

cy.get('.ico-register').should('have.css', 'cursor', 'pointer')
cy.get('.ico-register').should('have.css', 'color', 'rgb(74, 178, 241)')
```

Cypress [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/hover#Workarounds) also recommend this library.